# Excel auto-insert rows when data range expands

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create an advanced attendance sheet for my job. We have a sheet for each shift with the names of each employee. We type hours in across the row with the employee name. We have a separate schedule sheet. Currently, I am using the formula

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Schedule!$A$4:$A$35,SMALL(IF($A$1=Schedule!$I$4:$I$35,ROW(Schedule!$A$4:$A$35)-3,""),ROW()-2)),"")`

to generate the names of the employees who are scheduled on the shift sheets.

As we continue to hire more employees, I need to find a way to have excel automatically insert the new name into the shift sheet in an auto-generated row so that the hours shift down with the employee and the range the formula covers automatically expands so that I do not need to create new rows to expand the bottom to show the full list.

Can anyone help with this?

[Shift Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPqPo.jpg)
[Schedule Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Sqe.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: As @help-info.de said, an example would be very helpful. An example of what your current schedule and shift sheets look like would also make it easier to understand what exactly your current formula is doing. If you just need to automatically change the size of the referenced area, check out [named ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-named-ranges) and [structured references to tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e).

Comment: @DavidP I added pictures of both sheets. We manually type in the hours worked on the shift sheets so I need a way to have excel automatically enter the new employees name in alphabetical order that doesn't require me to manually insert the row in the correct spot and that keeps the hours already recorded attached to the correct employee. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding exactly what your formula is doing since your screenshots don't have the row/column labels and it looks like they don't cover enough columns of the schedule sheet for me to see what data is being referenced. So when you add a new employee, you insert them into the middle of the schedule sheet so they're in alphabetical order, then the formula updates the employee list on the shift sheet but doesn't move the manually entered hours down, is that correct?

Comment: @DavidP yes. It also removes the last name on the list because the range the formula covers doesn't automatically increase.